# Why cannot remove head elements in a LinkedList in Python?

Tags: python, linked-list

My ListNode Class defined as follows:

```
class ListNode:
    val = None
    next = None
    def __init__(self, x):
        if isinstance(x, list) and len(x) >= 1:
            self.val = x[0]
            cur = self
            for i in range(1, len(x)):
                cur.next = ListNode(x[i])
                cur = cur.next
        else:
            self.val = x
            self.next = None

    def __repr__(self):
        list_str = ''
        cur = self
        while cur is not None:
            list_str += '{}->'.format(cur.val)
            cur = cur.next
        list_str += 'NULL'
        return list_str
```

and my remove elements `Solution` class as follows:

```
class Solution:
    def removeElements(self, head, val):
        if head is not None and isinstance(head, ListNode):
            while head is not None and head.val == val:
                del_node = head
                head = head.next
                del del_node
            if head is None:
                return None

            cur = head
            while cur is not None:
                if cur.next is not None and cur.next.val == val:
                    del_node = cur.next
                    cur.next = del_node.next
                    del del_node
                else:
                    cur = cur.next
        return head
```

My test code is as follows:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    node_list = [1,1,1,2,3,6,3,2,7,6,8,10,12,8,1,4,1]
    head = ListNode(node_list)
    print(head)
    del_elements = [2, 3, 6, 1]
    sol = Solution()
    for element in del_elements:
        print('-'*15,'do delete elements {}'.format(element),'-'*15)
        sol.removeElements(head, element)
        print(head)
```

if I just take `sol.removeElements(...)` instead of `head = sol.removeEelements(...)`, I can not remove the first elements 1, **but I can remove the middle elements 1 in the linkedlist**, I want to know the reasons?

Comment: When you're writing Python, you should write Python, not Java. There is no reason for Solution to be a class; in ListNode `val` and `next` are instance attributes so do not need to be declared at class level; and Python loops iterate over the thing itself, not a counter, so `for i in range(len(x))` is almost always wrong.

Comment: `removeElements()` does not directly change `head`, it only returns the updated value of `head` - which you then ignore.  You need to assign the return value back to `head` in order for any changes to the start of the list to have any effect.

Comment: Assigning to a function's parameter has no effect on the variable whose value you passed to the function. (And you should almost never use `del`.)

Answer (score 0):

You are ignoring the return value of `sol.removeElements()`, which is the new `head` reference. The `del head` operation in the method only deletes the local reference, not any other references to the head!

So what happens now is that the code in the `if __name__ == '__main__':` maintains their reference to the old head while the `sol.removeElements()` method moves it's *local* `head` reference forward; after removing `2` and `3` and `6`:

```
# if __name__ == '__main__':
head -> ListNode(1).next -> ListNode(1).next -> ListNode(1).next -> ListNode(7).next -> ...

# inside sol.removeElements()
    # step 0
    head -> ListNode(1).next -> ListNode(1).next -> ListNode(1).next -> ListNode(7).next -> ...

    # step 1
    head -> ListNode(1).next -> ListNode(1).next -> ListNode(7).next -> ...

    # step 2
    head -> ListNode(1).next -> ListNode(7).next -> ...

    # step 3
    head -> ListNode(7).next -> ...

    # at the end
    return head
```

By ignoring `return head` there you left the first `head` reference unchanged.

Use:

```
head = sol.removeElements(head, element)
```

to update that reference.

Removing nodes in the middle of the linked list works because nothing else is holding direct references to those nodes. The `if __name__ == '__main__':` code only references `head`, so each time you want to 'look' at the linked list values code explicitly goes from `head` to each `.next` reference. You changed those `.next` references, and that is what makes the values in the middle 'disappear'.

Note: the `del` statements in your method are entirely redundant and **do not actually need to be executed**. They only remove the local reference from the function local namespace to the object. The node objects themselves do not get deleted by a `del` statement, `del` deletes references, not objects. Python objects are deleted only when the number of references drops to 0, so if an object is actually deleted is a mere side effect of a `del` statement.

So

```
def removeElements(self, head, val):
    while head is not None and head.val == val:
        head = head.next
    cur = head
    while cur.next is not None:
        if cur.next.val == val:
            cur.next = cur.next.next
        else:
            cur = cur.next
    return head
```

would be more than enough to achieve the same.

Comment: but with del head clause and just removeElement(head, element), I can remove the element 1 in middle of the raw linkedlist, without head = sol.removeElement(head, element), I can not remove the elements 1 at the head of linkedlist....

Comment: I have post the solution of this problem, but I want the reasons for such problem...

Comment: @siliconMaigc: the `del` statements are **not actually needed**. They only remove the local name, the reference in the function. You can safely remove all the `del` statements in the method with no change in behaviour.

Comment: @siliconMaigc: what you appear to be missing is that names are just references too. Everything in Python is a link. The `.next` attributes are links, but so are the `head` and `cur` and `del_node` variables, and you can have any number of such links (references) to a given object. You can't tell other references to stop referencing your object and reference a different object.

Comment: @Martjin Pieters:thanks for your hint, but my major problem is why if I do not use head = removeElement(...) I can not remove the head elements, in debugger, I found that if the the id(head) and id(return value head) is the same, but after del their id(.) is different..

Comment: @siliconMaigc: yes, I'm telling you that that's **correct**. You can't remove the head from this linked list any other way. You can't alter the `head` reference in the main body of the code from inside a method.

Comment: @siliconMaigc: and it is not the `del` that does this, you can remove the `del` statements, and the `head` that is returned will still be a different object because **in your method you assigned a different reference to `head`**, when you used `head = head.next`.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the while loop, you are moving the head to next before deleting the del_node. You may need to delete the node first and then move to next

```
while head is not None and head.val == val:
     del_node = head
     del del_node
     head = head.next
if head is None:
     return None
```

Comment: I have tried your solution , but it does not worked...the result is same. but thank you anyway.